# Validation for string

Tags: javascript

I want to validate a username using Javascript. I have validated if media name is null. Now I want to check special characters are not taken except space.

```
<input type="text" name="medianame" id="medianame" value="" required="required">    
<a class="edit" href="" id="edit" onclick="return chk_val()">Save</a>    
<script>
function chk_val() {
    if (document.getElementById('medianame').value == "") {
        alert("Please enter name");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }    
}
</script>
```

Comment: So please be specific about exactly which characters are to be allowed in the field. (And a terminology thing: you haven't validated for null, you've checked for an empty string.)

Comment: only characters like a to z and A to Z and space are allowed. Yes i mean empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to test whether a string contains only the characters you want to allow:

```
/^[a-z ]+$/i
```

...or test for characters that aren't allowed:

```
/[^a-z ]/i
```

Use the [`.test()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) in your function as follows:

```
function chk_val() {
    var val = document.getElementById('medianame').value;
    if (val === "") {
        alert("Please enter name");
        return false;
    } else if (/[^a-z ]/i.test(val)) {
        alert("Please enter only letters or spaces");
        return false;
    }
    return true;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function chk_val()
{
    var error = false;
    var name = document.getElementById('medianame').value;
    if (name == "")
        error = true;
    else if( /^[A-z ]+$/.test(name) == false)
        error = true;

    if(error)
    {
        alert("Please enter correct name");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to have a single generic error message (how does the user know what "correct" is?) you can remove the `name == ""` test because your regex does that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This will check for all the expressions possible. You can filter your needs from this.

```
var yourExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g;
```

Then you can match like

```
var yourStr = document.getElementById('medianame').value;
if( yourStr.match(yourExp) == True ){
    alert('Matched');
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, so you need `true`, not `True` - but in any case the `.match()` method won't ever actually return a boolean, so...